# Substitution in a parabolic equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, substitution

I've been given the parabolic equation:

$ 3 \frac{∂^2u}{∂x^2} + 6\frac{∂^2u}{∂x∂y} + 3 \frac{∂^2u}{∂y^2}  - \frac{∂u}{∂x} - 4\frac{∂u}{∂y} + u = 0$

The questions ask you to find the characteristic coordinates and then put into canonical form. Which I have done. The canonical form being:

$ \frac{∂^2u}{∂η^2} = \frac{∂u}{∂ξ} + \frac{1}{3}\frac{∂u}{∂η} - \frac{1}{3}u  $

However I can't work through the last part of the question which says:

Use the substitution $u(ξ, η) = e^{λξ + µη}v(ξ, η)$ and find the constants $λ$ and $µ$ such that the equation can be further reduced to:

$ \frac{∂v}{∂ξ} = v\frac{∂^2v}{∂η^2}$

for some constant $v$ which you also need to identify.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What did you get when you tried using the substitution?

Comment: The only bit I'm not sure on is the initial substitution, I should be able to do the reduction once I've got the new substituted equation.